Restored GPG keys are invisible
I did an rsync -a backup of ~/.gnupg and an ensuing restore using the same method:
$ ls -l ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/
total 24
-rw------- 1 dustin dustin 3789 Jul 22 00:01 21CE5A648FC098016B210F19C5894CA090AC8FA0.key
-rw------- 1 dustin dustin 3787 Jul 22 00:01 29E446B279D1C67463DEA9546D2490DBC026E99B.key
-rw------- 1 dustin dustin 3787 Jul 22 00:01 3B5CEDC2D9BE791009DA185BAA4C80A9B1CE9996.key
-rw------- 1 dustin dustin 3789 Jul 22 00:01 3FC073BE0F3A6EDBFC7D28E07A0C287C7D9DB129.key
-rw------- 1 dustin dustin 3787 Jul 22 00:01 92CF31DD4DEA6DC2AB95E4E44D91DF191BF59E2A.key
-rw------- 1 dustin dustin 3789 Jul 22 00:01 E7492BF0A909568CD2F40744E3BD4FC466825B4B.key

(It's odd that they all have the same date, but at least it's in the past.)
Nothing is showing under --list-secret-keys. When I do "gpg --armor --export " with one of the IDs in the filenames above, it says "nothing exported".
I don't really mind regenerating keys in this case, but I'd like to understand what's going on here. All search results that I found on the matter were due either to permissions/ownership or, in one case, the GPG version. However, I spot-checked the permissions/owners and they looked right, and, given the rsync option, I wouldn't expect that to be an issue.
I'm [currently] using GPG 2.4.7 on Manjaro 24. I do not have access to the original environment, which was Pop OS (probably 22).

This is more a [unix.se] question than a Stack Overflow one; we're strictly focused on writing code.

(Start with validating your public keys -- most operations on private keys start from the associated public key; indeed, gpg --armor --export only exports the public key and doesn't do anything with the private key at all; I don't think it ever tries to read any of the files you show in the question; typically it'll be working from ~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx)

Yes, you're right about the site. I didn't even think about it.
